# How about a button to re-post/ask-again a question?

Tags: feature-request

May be we can add a button to ask a previously asked question again to bring it to the top. May be some one else will be able to find it this time and anser. And it will be nice if a rule is put like a question can be "re-asked" only once in a week or so and a total of 5 times or so.. What you think?

Comment: How is it different to this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: I am talking about a "Button" a UI enhancement instead of a following a guideline..

Comment: So a dupe of a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/nudge-feature

Comment: I can't believe I just voted to close, but the **real** dupe of this question was literally one lower on the questions list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/how-about-we-add-random-chaos-to-so-by-allowing-arbitrary-bumping-of-questions-with-the-click-of-a-button

Comment: Another dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/please-add-a-way-to-bump-questions-back-to-the-front-page

Comment: Do we have any reports available showing some statistics like the number of questions unanswered, number of voted high questions unanswered like that. May be such an analysis will provide us more insight on this kind of feature is needed or not. If a question is beneficial for masses if answered, but stayed unanswered because the right people didn't see it or no one who viewed that knew the right answer, then I think that we need such a feature. I think we should focus on the quality of the content as much as we do for the quantity.

Answer (score 9):

We definitely won't be doing that.

Here's what I recommend:

[Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Waht is the probabilty of an SO user to find that link, practice that guideline and be a responsible contributer? If all netizens followed best practices we may never need this reputation based system here right. My suggestion is to make things better. I don't get why people are so reluctant to adopting features that may make things easier :(

Comment: Don't get why people don't use the search or look at the FAQ either.

Comment: @Faiz: we all think it is as easy as it should be. An additional button would be redundant functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The downside of a "bump" button:

By having this be a simple, one-click deal, it becomes very easy for people to essentially keep their questions on the active list, without any real activity going on with them. This creates a vicious circle where many questions are competing for the active attention, as armies of us code monkeys are sitting there clicking the "bump" button over and over like hamsters in a lab experiment. I wish I could see the situation where that *wouldn't* happen, but let's be honest -- a lot of people want their question to receive a lot of attention, and if even only 1% of SO's user base did this, madness and chaos would still ensue.

Yeah, I have no faith in fellow humans.

Comment: This question on SU had its own bump button: http://superuser.com/revisions/12450/list

Comment: Also, what does your grumpy look like?

Comment: @random: I didn't want to call anyone out specifically, but users of that ilk were *exactly* what I'd had in mind. And my grumpy's appearance is probably a binnable offense, so let's not go there. :)

Answer (score 1):

How will this be beneficial to the community?  It will lead to questions being reposted as exact duplicates, which will either be closed very quickly by the community (wasting the time of those who look at the question to answer it, then realise that it is a dupe), or the answers will be spread out too much rather than being collated in one place.

Instead, draw people's attention to your current question.  There they will see answers already provided, which may give them a starting point (e.g. this kind of worked, this didn't work, etc.).  For more information on how to draw attention to the post, see the link that Jeff and random have provided ([How to get attention for your old unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)).